# creating a "for" loop that returns different amounts of characters

Tags: java

I have a class called `SnowFallReport`, and when an object is created from it, it randomly assigns a number from 1-20 to a field called `snowFall`. The purpose is to generate a fictitious snow report with random snow amounts. Then I'm trying to create a method that can display a certain number of asterisks based on the number in the `snowFall` field. A hint was given to me that I'm supposed to use the `for` loop to do so, and I just cannot figure out how to word it correctly. Code follows:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class SnowFallReport
{   

    // Random amount of snow
    private double snowAmount;

    // Default constructor creates random amount and assigns to snowAmount
    public SnowFallReport()
    {
        Random snowFall = new Random();
        snowAmount = (snowFall.nextDouble() * 20);
    }

    public double getSnow()
    {
        return snowAmount;
    }

    public String getStars()
    {
        for (int starCount = 0; starCount >= snowAmount; starCount++)
            return "*";
         /* This is what I thought it should be^ but it turns out I need a return
 statement outside of the for loop. I've tried a couple of different ways with no luck */

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SnowFallReport day1 = new SnowFallReport();
        String lol = day1.getStars();
        System.out.print(lol);
    }   
}
```

Comment: The `return` statement will cut off the loop. Program Flow will exit the function.

Answer (score 1):

In your `getStars` method, initialize a `StringBuffer` (say, `sb`), then in your for loop, append a '*' character for every snow amount.  Then, return `sb.toString()`.

Also, your loop condition in your for-loop is wrong.  The loop will continue if the statement is true, not false.

The following method should work:

```
public String getStars()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int starCount = 0; starCount < snowAmount; starCount++)
        sb.append("*");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int starCount = 0; starCount >= snowAmount; starCount++)
```

Says startCount = 0. While startCount >= snowAmount do the loop then increment startCount.

```
for (int starCount = 0; starCount <= snowAmount; starCount++)
```

Also: the return straight after the for loop will break the loop - you need to add a * to a buffer and then return the buffer after you've done the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple for loop for you that will return the number of stars.

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int starCount = 0; starCount <= snowAmount; starCount++)
        sb.Append("* ");
    return sb;
```

You could also try yield return which will return a star, then continue with the loop.

```
    for (int starCount = 0; starCount <= snowAmount; starCount++)
        yield return "*";
```

Also your greater sign should have been a less than sign :)

Comment: This is Java, not C#. (Hence, `.append()` instead of `.Append()`, and there is no `yield return` in Java.)

Comment: Also < instead of <= I believe.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int starCount = 0; starCount < snowAmount; starCount++) {
    sb.append('*');
}
return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also initialize the string like

```
char[] c = new char[snowFall];
Arrays.fill(c, '*');
System.out.println(new String(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use generators from QuickCheck library, it is really cool in terms of pre-existing [PrimitiveGenerators](http://quickcheck.java.net/nonav/javadoc/net/java/quickcheck/generator/PrimitiveGenerators.html)

It's easy as

```
Generator<String> generator = PrimitiveGenerators.strings(5,20);
for (int i=0;i<10;i++) {
  String randomString = generator.next();
  ...
}
```